# How to filter data using Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, e-commerce

I am trying to build an e-commerce api using Spring Boot 3 and Hibernate 6. I am stuck with filtering Products.Java class. I could not find any kind of result on the internet etc. How can i filter some of those fields using Hibernate 6? I need a way to do it, if someone can provide me i would appreciate a lot.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 10, message = "{validation.sku.size.too_short}")
    @Size(max = 100, message = "{validation.sku.size.too_long}")
    private String sku;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 5, message = "{validation.title.size.too_short}")
    @Size(max = 150, message = "{validation.title.size.too_long}")
    private String title;

    @Column(length = 300)
    private String short_desc;

    @Column
    private String long_desc;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal tax;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(100)
    @Column
    private int discount;

    @Column
    private int stock_amount;

    @Column
    private int stock_alarm_limit;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, max = 200)
    @URL
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String slug;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean featured = false;

    @Column
    private String image;

    @Column
    private boolean new_product;

    @Column
    private int likes = 0;

    @NotNull(message = "Status field can not be null")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private StatusZeroAndOne status;

    @Column
    private double witdh;

    @Column
    private double length;

    @Column
    private double height;

    @Column
    private boolean builtIn = false;
    
    

    @NotNull(message = "Please provide your brand")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Brand brand;

    @NotNull(message = "Please provide your category")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    @NotNull(message = "Creation Time can not be null")
    @CreationTimestamp
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    @Column(name = "create_at", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime createAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
    @Column(name = "update_at")
    private OffsetDateTime updateAt;

}
```

i looked on the internet and they says i can not use the Criteria API with Hibernate 6. I am looking for a best practice to filter those data optionally.

Comment: This is only an entity, which is a representation of your table. If you want to "filter" you would need to write a query to filter the data, or write a view to display the query  you want and a readonly entity/repository over that.

Comment: How you normally do queries with Spring Data JPA is like this: you write methods in a repository interface that represent the queries you want to do. See [a tutorial about Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Please ask specific examples by mentioning which attribute to be used for filtering.

Comment: I have to write end-point and filter the data below:

q: search query (optional)
categories: category ids (optional)
brands: brand ids (optional)
price1: begining price(optional)
price2: ending price(optional)
page: active page number (optional, default: 0)
size: record count in a page (optional, default: 20) sort : sort field name (optional, default: category_id) type: sorting type (optional, default: asc)